# ecma script for in loop and hasOwnProperty have a strange behaviour

Tags: json, typescript, for-loop

I would like to transform an object got from a NoSQL Database using a DTO, so, I inspect the object in a `for..in` loop to get only what I want to keep:

```
for (const attribute in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(attribute)) {
        console.log(`${attribute} belongs to object!`);
    }
}
```

I wonder why :

- I have to use `hasOwnProperty` method as I loop over the object to get attributes
- my object have a 'nutriments' attribute, but... never consoled

Here's a portion of the original object :

```
...
nutriments:
   { sugars: 6.5,
     'nova-group_serving': 4,
     fiber_value: 2.5,
     'nutrition-score-uk_100g': 1,
     energy_value: 1160,
     salt_100g: 1.08,
     'nutrition-score-uk': 1,
     fiber_100g: 2.5,
     proteins: 8.5,
     'nova-group_100g': 4,
     carbohydrates_unit: 'g',
     'saturated-fat_100g': 0.4,
     'nutrition-score-fr_100g': 1,
     salt_unit: 'g',
     'saturated-fat_unit': 'g',
     sugars_100g: 6.5,
     sugars_value: 6.5,
     'saturated-fat_value': 0.4,
     carbohydrates_value: 49.2,
     fat_unit: 'g',
     fiber: 2.5,
     proteins_value: 8.5,
     fat_value: 4.3,
     sugars_serving: 5.13,
     sodium_value: 0.43200000000000005,
     fiber_serving: 1.98,
     sodium_unit: 'g',
     energy_serving: 916,
     sodium_serving: 0.34099999999999997,
     proteins_unit: 'g',
     carbohydrates: 49.2,
     energy: 1160,
     salt_value: 1.08,
     sodium_100g: 0.43200000000000005,
     'nova-group': 4,
     'saturated-fat_serving': 0.316,
     proteins_serving: 6.72,
     'nutrition-score-fr': 1,
     energy_100g: 1160,
     energy_unit: 'kJ',
     fiber_unit: 'g',
     'carbon-footprint-from-known-ingredients_product': 416,
     sugars_unit: 'g',
     proteins_100g: 8.5,
     'carbon-footprint-from-known-ingredients_100g': 75.6,
     carbohydrates_serving: 38.9,
     salt_serving: 0.8530000000000001,
     fat_serving: 3.4,
     salt: 1.08,
     carbohydrates_100g: 49.2,
     'saturated-fat': 0.4,
     fat_100g: 4.3,
     fat: 4.3,
     'carbon-footprint-from-known-ingredients_serving': 59.7,
     sodium: 0.43200000000000005 },
...
```

I edit my for in loop to trace "attributes" and the attribute "nutriments" was listed, but... `result['nutriments']` is undefined and `result.hasOwnProperty('nutriments')` returns false...

```
for (const attribute in result) {
    console.log(`Discovering ${attribute} belongs to object!`);

    if (result.hasOwnProperty(attribute)) {
        console.log(`${attribute} belongs to object!`);
    }
}
```

This behaviour is observable for some other object attributes, but I can get the attribute value with a `result.attributeName`.

So, what can explain this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

`hasOwnProperty` returns `false` for attributes that are inherited. My guess would be that the `nutriments` property is in fact inherited by this object. We use it to actually avoid some of the inherited properties.

Another possibility is that the object is either a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) or has some of its properties protected with [`.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), making them either not iterable or not "get-able".

More info would be needed for proper diagnosis / solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this question... I found the solution exploring my own mongoose Schema, even if MongoDB returns the whole content of the document, this one is handled by the defined Schema, and... i forgot to add the "nutriments" property.